# Can an Android process host multiple Dalvik VM's?

Tags: android

Can an Android process ever host multiple Dalvik VM's? If so, what scenarios can cause this to occur, and what would be the benefit of having multiple VM's in the same process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, multiple VMs per process is not supported.